# Does a list of elements' orders in an abelian group determine the group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

Let $G=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ be an **abelian** group and let $m_1\leq m_2\leq \ldots \leq m_n$ be the list of orders of all the elements of $G$.

E.g., for the Klein 4-group $V$ we get the list $1,2,2,2,$ and for the cyclic group $C_4$ we get the list $1,2,4,4$.

Does the list of orders determine $G$? If not, is it true for $p$-groups?

Thanks!

Comment: [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313001?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) is a link to a paper claiming to have proven that (for abelian groups) the order sequence determines the group.  (I have not checked the proof).  The claim is not true for non-abelian groups, there are counterexamples for groups of order $16$, for example. (see, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729611/is-a-finite-group-uniquely-determined-by-the-orders-of-its-elements)).

Comment: Thanks @lulu for this information!